# Google Map strange behaviour- marker info Window displays info always from the same marker

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

I have map with multiple different colors markers with some info window. Everything works OK except when I click on some marker (I have 5 of them on example) it switches my cursor on, let's say, the 4-th  marker and displays info window always from that marker. So it displays always the same info window.
It is small html file, so I would appreciate if someone knows the solution for this.
I tried also and with `google.maps.event.addDomListener` because I suppose that there is the problem but it is the same behaviour.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Google Maps Javascript API v3 Example: Loading the data from an XML</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="downloadxml.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[





     // global "map" variable
      var map = null;






function initialize() {

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.907787,-79.359741),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        });
      // Read the data from example.xml
      downloadUrl("example7.xml", function(doc) {
        var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
        var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          // obtain the attribues of each marker
          var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
          var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
          var html = markers[i].getAttribute("html");




        var severity = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("severity"));

        var color= "66FF33";


       if (severity == 0) color = "66FF33";
       else if (severity == 1) color = "990099";
        else if (severity == 2) color = "00CCFF";


        var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/" + color,
        new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(10, 34));


      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: point,
                map: map,
                icon: pinImage,

            });

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        var alarmanchor1='<span class="url"><a href="' + html;
        var alarmanchor2='" title="www" target="_blank">Event List</a></span>';
        var contentString=alarmanchor1+alarmanchor2;
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });




        }

      });
    }

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
  { 
    size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
  });


//]]>
</script> 

  </head> 
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()"> 


    <table border="1"> 
      <tr> 
        <td> 
           <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 1050px; height: 1200px"></div> 
        </td> 

      </tr> 
    </table> 


<script src="urchin.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script> 


  </body> 
</html>
```

My XML is:

```
<markers>

 <marker lat="43.65654" lng="-79.90138" html="http://www.google.com"  label="Marker One" severity="0" />
 <marker lat="43.91892" lng="-78.89231" html="http://www.yahoo.com" label="Marker Two" severity="1" />
 <marker lat="43.82589" lng="-79.10040" html="http://www.sport.com"  label="Marker Three" severity="2" />
  <marker lat="43.72589" lng="-79.60040" html="http://www.stackoverflow.com"  label="Marker Fourth" severity="3" />
   <marker lat="43.52589" lng="-79.70040" html="http://www.stackoverflow.com"  label="Marker Five" severity="4" />
 </markers>
```

Comment: Can you share the xml file also?

Comment: Hi Ersel. Thanks for answer I update it with my XML.

Comment: Ok, I will have a look again.

Comment: @Ersel one update I managed to change my code and now it does not switch on another marker but still shows url from the last marker in xml

Comment: google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
  return function(){
     var alarmanchor1='<span class="url"><a href="' + html;
  var alarmanchor2='" title="www" target="_blank">Event List</a></span>';
  var contentString=alarmanchor1+alarmanchor2;

    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
  
  }
  

        }) (marker, i));

Comment: As you can see above I changed addListener method.  I added additional function(marker,i) and now it stays on right marker when I click it but it stills read the url from the last html in XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your code to this so that it gets the correct url for each element.

```
<a href="' + html;
```

to

```
<a href="' +markers[i].getAttribute("html");
```

so the full code to your question is:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) { return function(){ var alarmanchor1='<span class="url"><a href="' +markers[i].getAttribute("html"); var alarmanchor2='" title="www" target="_blank">Event List</a></span>'; var contentString=alarmanchor1+alarmanchor2; infowindow.setContent(contentString); infowindow.open(map, marker); } }) (marker, i));
```

Comment: thank you for your efforts! I thought it was enough to just get html value but you were right! Can I ask you just two more question: for API 3 i do not need key to purchase?Because I would like to upload and transfer this file to some application server. And second question in API 3 how to change size of icon? Because if I change         new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(10, 34));   to new google.maps.Size(15, 30), my markers get cut off or with some red shadow. THANKS!!!!!!

Comment: No, you dont need key but it is free to get one so it not a problem. I am not sure, I use this tool create my markers.
http://powerhut.co.uk/googlemaps/custom_markers.php Glad to help :)